# How can I compare the time between an Iphone and a (web) server?

Tags: iphone, time, synchronization, client-server

I have an application made up of a server which sends occasional messages to Iphones. The latency between the two devices is important to the problem domain - if it takes less than a second for the message to arrive, everything's fine; if it takes more than 5 seconds, there's almost certainly a problem. The server-side messages are time stamped with the server time.

Using the cellular data connection, we see occasional delays, but we can't quantify them, because there's no guarantee that the Iphone's clock is synchronized with the server; one our test phones, we see different times for different carriers.

Is there a simple way to synchronize time between the Iphone and the server? I've looked at (S)NTP, which seems to be the right way to go.

Any alternatives? We only need to be accurate within seconds, not milli seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact situation is, so this may be a non-solution, but:

Presuming that you want to figure out the latency between the phone and the server (and only this) at set intervals (decided by the server). Presuming also that the error checking is done server-side, instead of synchronizing clocks, you might go with a "ping" approach.

- Server pings client iPhone, and starts a stopwatch.
- Client immediately pings server.
- As soon as client ping reaches server, server stops the stopwatch and checks the time.

If I misunderstood your problem, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a somewhat simplistic solution is that you could have the phones tell the server what time they have at various times and keep a database table of deltas. Then adjust your reported timestamp to the serve's time r +/- the delta. iPhones are synced to the carrier's time server to the best of my knowledge. The other possibility is to have both the phone and server query a common time source on a daily basis. It's unlikely that the time would vary much over a single day.